# apple device UUid getting changed after installing the updated version on IOS 7

Tags: ios, ios7

To getting the user's device UUID in `objective c` I have using

```
[UIDevice currentDevice].identifierForVendor.UUIDString
```

In ios 6, now when I am trying to download the IOS-7 version of that app whole UUID getting changed. Not getting any clue how to solve this.

It's looking like this,

When installing the `IPA === 0849EC56-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-EF1625FB58C8`
​After downloading the same app from app store it's giving `UUID  - 285E6931-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-08D85052E180​`

Answer (score 0):

UUIDString is not unique for iOS device its unique for your app.

Read the apple doc

identifierForVendor
An alphanumeric string that uniquely identifies a device to the app’s vendor. (read-only)

```
@property(nonatomic, readonly, retain) NSUUID *identifierForVendor
```

The value of this property is the same for apps that come from the same vendor running on the same device. A different value is returned for apps on the same device that come from different vendors, and for apps on different devices regardless of vendor.

Normally, the vendor is determined by data provided by the App Store. If the app was not installed from the app store (such as enterprise apps and apps still in development), then a vendor identifier is calculated based on the app’s bundle ID. The bundle ID is assumed to be in reverse-DNS format.

Comment: so, UUIDString can be changed when the app version will change??? which is occurring my case???

Comment: not depend on the app version, depends on the iOS version. What purpose you are using UUID ?

Comment: i was using it for schedule calendar date. IT was fine in IOS 6 When have download it new version then previous data is not there

Comment: what is your problem exactly ? please explain clearly